# Error encoding text: Unable to encode text using charset windows-1256

Tags: java, class, encoding, jgrasp

I wrote a program but when I want to save it, I got an error saying:

> Error encoding text. Unable to encode text using charset windows-1256. First bad character is at line 13 column 40.

I don't understand what the error is. I'm using jGRASP. This is my program:

```
public class Point {
double x, y;
int counter=0; 

Point (double ex, double why){
x=ex;
y=why; 
counter++; }

public Distance (double x1, double y1) {
/* using Pythagoras c^2 = a^2 + b^2 
 where a is the horizontal distance (x − x1)
 and b is the vertical distance (y − y1)
 and c is the distance */
double a, b, c;
a = Math.pow(x - x1);
b = Math.pow(y - y1);
c = Math.sqrt(a + b);
}

public product (double x1, double y1) {
// using the dot product rule =>  A.B=(a1.b1)+(a2.b2)
double product = (x * y)+(x1 * y1);
}

public void setX (double ex){
x=ex; }

public void setY (double why) {
y=why ; } 

public double getX() {
return x; }

public double getY() {
return y; } 

public int getCounter() {
return counter; } 

} // end of class
```

Comment: Please keep comments relevant and meaningful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 13 column 40 is character code 8722. This looks like a minus sign (code 45) but is not. There is another of the same at line 14, column 36. Replace these with normal minus signs and the file can be saved under 1256 encoding (your system default) if there are no similar problems. Most likely you pasted the code or at least the comment from some non-code source such as a web site or MS Word document, and that is how those got in there.

You can enter any Unicode BMP in the editor, but when saving, your system default encoding will be used if you don't specify another. 1256 does not support all those characters. You can use "File" > "Save As" to save in another encoding if absolutely necessary (but you don't want to do that in this case).